# how to know ip address of a computer by using its pc name in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, chat, ip-address

I am currently working on a chat application.
For connecting client to server i have to enter the IP address of server manually as we are using LAN and every time server system connected it's ip gets changed.
So is there a way to find the ip address of a specific computer by just using its pc name.
I am currently using Java for implementation.

Comment: *ip address of a specific computer by just using its pc name* that is what DNS is

Comment: see this link- https://askubuntu.com/questions/736109/how-to-get-pc-name-from-ip-address . I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("www.java2novice.com");
System.out.println(host.getHostAddress());
```

This link should be help you. http://www.java2novice.com/java_networking/ip_by_host_name/

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I'm not sure on what you mean by long-term value. When you pass the machineName/Hostname to the method it fetches you the IP without any issues. Only it will throw an UnkownHostException when the machine name provided is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("Host_Name"); // just write the host name of server machine
    System.out.println(ip.getHostAddress());
```

I think that will help you.

Comment: put the above code inside the try-catch block or throw the UnknownHost Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the only IP address of your Ubuntu PC then type:

```
$ hostname -I
```